# How to combine probabilities, weighting by strength of evidence?

Tags: probability, classification, bayesian, bayes, interpolation

Let's say that I'm trying to classify an item as a member of either class c1, class c2, class c3, etc. out of a large number of classes. In my training set, feature A appears only once; it happens to appear on an item belonging to class c1. Feature B appears 100 times, and 99 of those times, it appears on an item belonging to class c2 (let's say it appears on class c3 the remaining time). So feature B seems to be very predictive of an item's class. The conditional probabilities are as follows:

- P(c1|A) = 1, since the class of the only item with which A was observed was c1;
- P(c1|B) = 0;
- P(c2|A) = 0;
- P(c2|B) = .99, since 99 out of 100 times that B was observed, the class was c2.

Now imagine I am trying to predict the class of a novel item that has feature A and feature B. Simply classifying by virtue of the probabilities above would assign the novel item to class A (if P(c1|A) and P(c2|B) are compared directly), or else would give c1 and c2 equal probability of zero (since P(c1|A, B) and P(c2|A, B) each equal zero). But this is clearly a bad idea because the strength of the evidence in support of c2 from B is so much greater than the evidence in support of c1 from A. Is there a principled way to weight these probabilities for this fact?

Of course, I know that you shouldn't include features that appear on only one item when doing classification; I just used this as an extreme example. The reason I'm asking about this is that I'm working on a problem where ideally I'd like to compute a coefficient a1, a2, a3 ... for each feature F1, F2, F3 ... based on the strength of the evidence that the feature provides, such that the probability estimate for a class c is given by a1*P(c|F1) + a2*P(c|F2) + a3*P(c|F3) + ... But I'm not sure what would be the most sensible way to do so.

Comment: The [multinomial logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) is the standard way of answering such questions...